# nodejs argparse - How to add a required argument

Tags: node.js, required, args

I have this code-

```
let parser = new ArgumentParser({
version: '0.0.1',
});
parser.addArgument(
['-s', '--server'],
{
    help: 'server <server>',
    required: true
}
);
parser.addArgument(
[ '-svc', '--service' ],
{
    help: 'service <serviceNum>'
}
);
```

I want my server to be a required argument. The above doesn't work. I still get it under optional args:

```
usage: apiclient.js [-h] [-v] -s SERVER [-svc SERVICE]

Optional arguments:
-h, --help            Show this help message and exit.
-v, --version         Show program's version number and exit.
-s SERVER, --server SERVER
                    server <server>
-svc SERVICE, --service SERVICE
                    service <serviceNum>
```

How can I have the "server" argument in the required args?

Answer (score 0):

I had to update argparser to 1.0.10.

And I had to create a subgroup:

```
const requiredArgs = parser.addArgumentGroup({ title: 'required arguments' 
});

requiredArgs.addArgument(
['-s', '--server'], {
    help: 'server <server>',
    required: true
}
);
```